# Error While creating Java Binding Library in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

we use xamarin for android and we are trying to integrate inmobi ([inmobi](https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/)) ads in to our app and while we try to create a Java Binding Library we get following errors.

```
Error   69  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.AdRequestFailedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'    
Error   70  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.AdRequestFailedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'    
Error   71  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.AdRequestFailedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p1'    
Error   72  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.AdRequestFailedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P1'    
Error   73  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.DismissAdScreenEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'    
Error   74  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.DismissAdScreenEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'    
Error   75  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.LeaveApplicationEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'   
Error   76  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.LeaveApplicationEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'   
Error   77  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.ShowAdScreenEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0'   
Error   78  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Androidsdk.ShowAdScreenEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'   
Error   67  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Monetization.LeaveApplicationEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' 
Error   68  The type 'Com.Inmobi.Monetization.LeaveApplicationEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'P0'
```

how should we fix it? or is there a another way to do it?

Comment: Because you are not providing enough detail about what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix them like these below?

Metadata.xml

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.inmobi.androidsdk']/class[@name='AdRequestFailedEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">p0_2</attr>`

Comment: @Muthu : Is this help you or are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: Yes it did help me. Answer shows how to solve those issues.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue  Com.Wikitude.Tracker.IObjectTrackerListener.cs(47,47): Error CS0102: The type 'TargetsLoadedEventArgs' already contains a definition for 'p0' (CS0102)  .....I tried to add   <attr path="/api/package[@name='Com.Wikitude.Tracker']/class[@name='ErrorLoadingTargetsEventArgs']/field[@name='p0']" name="managedName">P0</attr> but not working